# What is the correct syntax for validating user input?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement, for-loop

My code creates a set of sport results using a scanner, the user enters input in this format "Home team : Away team : Home score : Away score" - each part is split into a string in the array. I want to create an error message if one part is missing for example "Error, Home team seems to be missing" for each corresponding section however;

I am a beginner and have been trying to put an else-if condition in the for loop to help make this error message however I am doing something wrong judging by the amount of errors I am getting (delete this token).

Comment: You need to say what errors you're getting.

Comment: This isn't a very common way to grab scanner input, definitely not the easiest way. You should be grabbing 4 separate variables using the correct scanner.next function. Why ask someone to put it all in at once when you can just ask for each one? That ensures that no value cannot be input.

Comment: @s.gang Can you help me with this, I am new to Java

Answer (score 0):

There are some things you can do, like checking the values with an if statement. You can say something like:

```
if(stringIsEmpty)
{
    print ("Error");
} 
else
{
   /*Keep executing program*/
}
```

You could also use a try/catch block. This could help because if a string is null (empty), you can throw a null pointer exception and define it the way you want, like this:

```
try
{
    /*blank string code*/
}catch(NullPointerException e)
{
    System.out.println("Empty strings are not allowed");
}
```

Comment: Very helpful, could you help me with the syntax? I'm not to sure where to place it within my code

Comment: Sure I will update my answer and try my best to solve the issue

Comment: Results of a sports match for example if the input was      "Home team : Away team : Home score : Away score" Tthe output would be "Home Team [Home Score] | Away Team [Away Score]

Comment: So you just want that output after every game or just one game?

Comment: I want it to do as many games as the user wants (The array is 100 big so that is the limit) - I want it to stop with an error message if something is missing

Answer (score 0):

This code will help your program to validate the user-input as per the your requirements in your question, if any of the inputs is missed by the user it is reported to him:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Test4 {

public static void ismissing(int i)
{
    switch(i)
    {
      case 0:
      System.out.println("Home team missing");
      break;

      case 1:
      System.out.println("Away team missing");
      break;

      case 2:
      System.out.println("Home score missing");
      break;

      case 3:
      System.out.println("Away score missing");
      break;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);    
    System.out.println("Input as follows; ");    
    System.out.println("Home team : Away team : Home score : Away score");
    String str=scanner.nextLine();

    String array[]=str.split(":");



    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
        if(array[i].equals(" "))
        {
            ismissing(i);
            System.exit(0); //will exit program if something is missing
        }
    }

        System.out.println("Correct Input");

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be creating numerous games, I would recommend you make a `Game` class as this will make it easier to manage a `Game` object as opposed to 2 Strings and 2 Integer values. With a `Game` object you can also output your desired string output using the `toString` method of your `Game` object. When getting the user input, the criteria I used is such that team names cannot be blank and team scores cannot be less than 0. If the user enters and empty string or an invalid integer, then we simply output a message indicating the invalid input and have the user try again until they get valid input. If you want to exit when this happens you could change this to accommodate a graceful exit of the program when the user enters invalid data.

I made two methods in the main, one to get a valid String team name, and another to get a valid Integer for the score. Again if the user inputs invalid data we will loop until the input is valid.

Game Class:

```
public class Game
{
  String homeTeam = "";
  String awayTeam = "";
  int homeScore = -1;
  int awayScore = -1;

  public Game(String inHomeTeam, int inHomeScore, String inAwayTeam, int inAwayScore)
  {
    super();
    this.homeTeam = inHomeTeam;
    this.awayTeam = inAwayTeam;
    this.homeScore = inHomeScore;
    this.awayScore = inAwayScore;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return homeTeam + "[" + homeScore + "] | " + awayTeam + "[" + awayScore + "]";
  }

  public String getHomeTeam() {
    return homeTeam;
  }
  public void setHomeTeam(String homeTeam) {
    this.homeTeam = homeTeam;
  }
  public String getAwayTeam() {
    return awayTeam;
  }
  public void setAwayTeam(String awayTeam) {
    this.awayTeam = awayTeam;
  }
  public int getHomeScore() {
    return homeScore;
  }
  public void setHomeScore(int homeScore) {
    this.homeScore = homeScore;
  }
  public int getAwayScore() {
    return awayScore;
  }
  public void setAwayScore(int awayScore) {
    this.awayScore = awayScore;
  }  
}
```

Main

```
public class Main
{
  static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  static Game[] allGames;
  static String homeTeam = "";
  static String awayTeam = "";
  static int homeScore = -1;
  static int awayScore = -1;
  static int numberOfGames = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    numberOfGames = GetUserInt("How many games do you want to enter - 100 or less: ");
    if (numberOfGames > 100)
      numberOfGames = 100;
    allGames = new Game[numberOfGames];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGames; i++) {
      homeTeam = GetUserString("Enter the home team name: ");
      homeScore = GetUserInt("Enter the home team score: ");
      awayTeam = GetUserString("Enter the away team name: ");
      awayScore = GetUserInt("Enter the away team score: ");
      allGames[i] = new Game(homeTeam, homeScore, awayTeam, awayScore);
    }
    // output the users games
    for(Game curGame : allGames)
    {
      if (curGame != null)
        System.out.println(curGame.toString());
    }
  }

  private static String GetUserString(String prompt)
  {
    String input = "";
    while(true) {
      System.out.print(prompt);
      input = scanner.nextLine();
      if (input.length() > 0)
        return input;
      else
        System.out.println("Invalid input: Can not be empty string!");
    }
  }

  private static int GetUserInt(String prompt)
  {
    String input = "";
    while(true) {
      System.out.print(prompt);
      input = scanner.nextLine();
      if (input.length() > 0) {
        if (isValidInt(input)) {
          int value = Integer.parseInt(input);
          if (value >= 0) {
            return value;
          }
          else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input: Score can not be negative");
          }
        }
        else {
          System.out.println("Invalid input: Score must be a valid integer");
        }
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("Invalid input: Score can not be empty");
      }
    }
  }

  private static boolean isValidInt(String inString)
  {
    try {
      Integer.parseInt(inString);
      return true;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!